# how to split file and lines

Tags: sed, awk, scripting, tr

I have [a text file](http://www.calresco.org/pic3/calres3.par) like :

```
1_01                  { ; quite good spirals 


reset=2000 type=mandel passes=1
  corners=-0.6014129278/-0.5990935452/0.427747516/0.429487053
  params=0/0 float=y maxiter=1000 inside=0 outside=15
  distest=1/10/320/200 
  }

1_02                  { ; stringy one, with dist estimator
  reset=2000 type=mandel passes=1
  corners=-1.9228429644992/-1.9228427944992/-6.3749991620026e-008/6.375000\
  8379971e-008 params=0/0 float=y maxiter=1000 inside=0 outside=15
  distest=1/20/320/200
  }

1_03                  { ; OK, bit dull, not zoomed in far 
  reset=2000 type=mandel passes=1
  corners=0.3734922373/0.3820837907/-0.243292645/-0.23684898
  params=0/0 float=y maxiter=1000 inside=0 outside=15
  distest=1/10/320/200
  }

1_04                  { ; a mess, needs dist est
  reset=2000 type=mandel passes=1
  corners=-1.862224008886682/-1.86222400040936/-3.214020831358832e-009/3.1\
  43970347410528e-009 params=0/0 float=y maxiter=1000 inside=0
  outside=15 distest=1/10/320/200 
  }
```

and I would like to split it into files and lines like :

```
1_01 { ; quite good spirals
reset=2000
type=mandel
passes=1
corners=-0.6014129278/-0.5990935452/0.427747516/0.429487053
params=0/0
float=y
maxiter=1000
inside=0
outside=15
distest=1/10/320/200
}
```

Now I have made a bash script :

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# chmod +x s.sh
# ./s.sh
for f in *.txt; 
do  
 echo " found "$f " file ";
 #split -l 7 $f; 
 awk '/{/{n++}{print > n".p" }' $f
 echo $f "- split when { is found  and add p extension " ;
 rm $f;
 echo " input file " $f " is removed " ;
done

for f in *.p;   
do
 echo " in "$f " file replace space with newline and add par extension"
 # tr '{}' '()' < infile > outfile
 tr ' ' '\n' < $f >$f"ar"
 rm $f;
done

for f in *.par;     
do
 echo "remove blank= empty lines"
 sed -i '/^$/d' $f
done
```

It works , but can I do it better ?

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATED:** *simpified and tested in `gawk` (v.3.1.8) and `mawk` (v. 1.3.3)*

This awk script should do what you seem to be asking for; it may work on other awk implementations that support regular expression field- and record-separators:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {
  RS="}\n\n?"
  ORS="}\n"
  FS="\n"
  OFS="\n"
}

{
  # compress whitespace in first field
  gsub(/[ \t\n]+/," ",$1)

  # split remaining fields on whitespace
  for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) {
      gsub(/[ \t\n]+/,"\n",$i)
  }

  # remove double-newlines resulting from trailing whitespace
  gsub("\n\n+","\n",$0)

  print > NR".par"
}
```

---

Testing with your input as `file.txt`:

```
$ ./split.awk file.txt
```

then

```
$ cat 1.par
1_01 { ; quite good spirals 
reset=2000
type=mandel
passes=1
corners=-0.6014129278/-0.5990935452/0.427747516/0.429487053
params=0/0
float=y
maxiter=1000
inside=0
outside=15
distest=1/10/320/200
}
```

and

```
$ cat 3.par
1_03 { ; OK, bit dull, not zoomed in far 
reset=2000
type=mandel
passes=1
corners=0.3734922373/0.3820837907/-0.243292645/-0.23684898
params=0/0
float=y
maxiter=1000
inside=0
outside=15
distest=1/10/320/200
}
```

Comment: I have GNU Awk 4.0.1. It works, but the output is one file with par extension. It has also blank lines. I would like to split file into files having all data between { and }

Comment: That's odd - I tested it on GNU Awk 3.1.8 and 4.1.1, it would be unusual for features not to be backward-compatible. I will see if I can figure out what's different.

Comment: The double newlines confused me, too. I figured it out, though - we're translating spaces into newlines, right? So... if there are spaces at the head/tail of the line... you see what I mean? That's why I strip them from both ends in mine.

Comment: Ah yes thanks - I hadn't noticed that two of the records in the OP's example have trailing spaces. I managed to dispense with the extra gsub by changing the FS to `FS="[[:space:]]*\n[[:space:]]*"` - but I'm not sure that's necessarily more efficient.

Comment: May not be - but it's always better to understand what's going on at least. I hate it when a thing works one way and not another and I don't get why. I was just looking at the link, too. That's definitely CR/LF. But, of course, there won't be any of that in a copy/paste here.

Answer (score 2):

I put your example data in `./file` like:

```
cat >file <<\IN
# all of your example
IN
```

Then I did the following:

```
sed -n 's|\([^ ]*\) *{.*|/\1 {/,/}/w file.\1.par|p' file | 
sed -e 's/  */ /g;s/^ //;s/ $//;/./!d;/{/!y/ /\n/' -f - file
```

That uses one `sed` process to prune the data in the infile and edit it instream into a workable `sed` script for a second `sed` process.

The script that winds up being executed looks like...

```
/1_01 {/,/}/w file.1_01.par
/1_02 {/,/}/w file.1_02.par
/1_03 {/,/}/w file.1_03.par
/1_04 {/,/}/w file.1_04.par
```

...but it is only executed *after* the second `sed` does for each line in *file*...

```
... -e 's/  */ /g;s/^ //;s/ $//;/./!d;/{/!y/ /\n/' ...
```

...which first squeezes any sequence of spaces into a single space, removes a leading or trailing space if they remain, deletes empty lines entirely from output, and last translates all spaces into a `\n`ewline character for each line which does not match `{`.

So for each line number which matches `(section heading) *{.*` the second `sed` `w`rites it and all subsequent lines up to and including the next occurring `}` in input to `file.(section heading)` while the original infile is left unaffected.

After running that I did...

```
cat <./file.1_01.par
```

...and...

```
1_01 { ; quite good spirals 
reset=2000
type=mandel
passes=1
corners=-0.6014129278/-0.5990935452/0.427747516/0.429487053
params=0/0
float=y
maxiter=1000
inside=0
outside=15
distest=1/10/320/200
}
```

To run it just copy/paste those two `sed ...` lines into your terminal and substitute the *file* name for whatever is appropriate.

I also had a go at the [link](http://www.calresco.org/pic3/calres3.par) in your question...

```
sed -n 's|.\([^ ]*\) {.*|/\1 {/,/^}$/w \1.par|p' <<-IN |\ 
sed -e 's/.//;/{/!y/ /\n/' -f - all.par
    $(curl -s 'http://www.calresco.org/pic3/calres3.par' |
    tr -s '\r\n ' '\n  ' |tee all.par)
IN
```

That split out all of the `.par` functions into their own files - and handled the DOS line-endings:

```
ls -C
a46.par       bugeyed.par  flocks.par    iconw2b.par   manchaos.par  swirl5.par
aciddrop.par  burr.par     galaxy.par    juliland.par  mandelzm.par  trific.par
all.par       complex.par  highrise.par  lace.par      redgiant.par
angfish.par   eyeeye.par   iconvolc.par  lavaflow.par  scythe.par
```

They're all named for the function name.

```
cat galaxy.par

galaxy {;Chris Lucas
reset=1950
type=julia
center-mag=+0.03023290053994965/+0.26628255550711930/42.69126/1/67.5
params=-0.1582146627566066/0.6550294654497986
float=y
maxiter=30000
colors=000000GFF<28>x11z00z10<29>zx0zz0zz1<29>zzxzzzzzz<61>zV1zU0zU0zT0<\
28>z10z00z00y00<30>c00b11a11`22_22<25>FFF
}
```

Comment: Coud you make a bash script from all this commends ?

Comment: @Adam - how do you mean, exactly? You should just be able to run it as is. Maybe the edits make it clearer?

Comment: @Adam - ok, I have just realized that it could be far more simplified - and so I did so.

Answer (score 1):

Try csplit:  inputfile == `frac.txt`, output files == `frac[nn]` ( where nn>00, because file #00 is empty)

```
 csplit -f frac frac.txt /^1/ {*}
```

Answer (score 1):

Line formatting you can do just by `sed` alone:

```
sed -i 's/^\s*\|\s*$//g ; s/\s\s*/ /g ; /[{}]/!s/ /\n/g ; /^\s*$/d' *.txt
```